# WebSocket fired notifications

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, websocket, windows-phone

Is it possible to fire windows phone notification or change live tile by WebSocket event?

I want to eg. change live tile content remotely from server.
App should have such connection and it should work without running app.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using [push notification for windows phone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402558(v=vs.105).aspx) .

Below are the steps

1. Your app requests a push notification URI from the Push client service.
2. The Push client service negotiates with the Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS), and MPNS returns a notification URI to the Push client service.
3. The Push client service returns the notification URI to your app.
4. Your app can then send the notification URI to your cloud service.
5. When your cloud service has info to send to your app, it uses the notification URI to send a push notification to MPNS.
6. MPNS routes the push notification to your app.

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202970(v=vs.105).aspx) MSDN page  to understand tile notification in detail.